# How to invoke StaticMethodExpr.eval?

Tags: java, clojure, abstract-syntax-tree

I am following [this series](http://blog.fogus.me/2012/04/25/the-clojurescript-compilation-pipeline/) to learn how clojure compiler works.

I tried to invoke `eval` method of `StaticMethodExpr` using below codes

```
(ns clojure.lang
  (:use clojure.core)
  (:import [clojure.lang Compiler Compiler$C]))

(def form (read-string "(+ 1 1)") )

(def expr (Compiler/analyze Compiler$C/EXPRESSION form))

(.eval expr)
```

but no luck and throw `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
Unhandled java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
   Can't call public method of non-public class: public
   java.lang.Object clojure.lang.Compiler$StaticMethodExpr.eval()
```

Is there anything  I was missing or is this [a bug in jdk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38060382/2163429) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can still call the method using reflection:

```
(let [m (.getDeclaredMethod clojure.lang.Compiler$Expr "eval" (make-array Class 0))]
  (.setAccessible m true)
  (defn -eval [expr]
    (.invoke m expr (object-array 0))))

(-eval (clojure.lang.Compiler/analyze clojure.lang.Compiler$C/EXPRESSION '(+ 1 2)))
;= 3
```

This should be good enough if your goal is to explore.

A reflection-free Java program could call this method on the result of analysing `(+ 1 2)` via a reference of type `clojure.lang.Compiler.HostExpr`, which is public, even though neither the declaring interface of `clojure.lang.Compiler.Expr` nor the actual runtime type are public, so I suppose it is somewhat surprising that `setAccessible` is required.